# index.html not found payara micro

Tags: gradle, welcome-file, payara-micro

I have a `Java` application and I am using `Payara Micro 4.1.2.174` to deploy it. I am trying to configure the `index.html` file, which I placed in the folder `src/main/webapp`. However, no matter what I do, the file is not reachable, I am getting a 404 when trying to access it on the localhost: `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. I am building the war file using gradle. I also checked the built war file and the index.html file is at the root of the archive.

I am deploying my application at `/`, all the paths are also available starting from `/`:

> Loading application [ROOT] at [/]

I tried adding following in the `glassfish-web.xml` file, it didn't help:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/</context-root>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</glassfish-web-app>
```

Is there anything that I am missing? Is it possible to have an `index.html` in Payara Micro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with my setup: I am using JAX-RS and the class that extends `Application` was annotated with `@ApplicationPath("/")` which somehow caused the default behaviour to be overwritten. I changed that annotation and now everything works as expected, with the expected `WAR` structure.